# Languages like Tcl that have configurable syntax?

Tags: programming-languages, syntax

I'm looking for a language that will let me do what I could do with Clipper years ago, and which I can do with Tcl, namely add functionality in a way other than just adding functions.

For example in Clipper/(x)Harbour there are commands #command, #translate, #xcommand and #xtranslate that allow things like this:

```
#xcommand REPEAT; 
   => DO WHILE .T. 
#xcommand UNTIL <cond>; 
  =>     IF (<cond>); 
             ;EXIT; 
         ;ENDIF; 
     ;ENDDO 

LOCAL n := 1
REPEAT
    n := n + 1
UNTIL n > 100
```

Similarly, in Tcl I'm doing

```
proc process_range {_for_ project _from_ dat1 _to_ dat2 _by_ slice} {
    set fromDate [clock scan $dat1]
    set toDate   [clock scan $dat2]

    if {$slice eq "day"} then {set incrementor [expr 24 * 60]}
    if {$slice eq "hour"} then {set incrementor 60}

    set method DateRange

    puts "Scanning from [clock format $fromDate -format "%c"] to [clock format $toDate -format "%c"] by $slice"
    for {set dateCursor $fromDate} {$dateCursor <= $toDate} {set dateCursor [clock add $dateCursor $incrementor minutes]} {
        # ...
    }
}
process_range for "client" from "2013-10-18 00:00" to "2013-10-20 23:59" by day
```

Are there any other languages that permit this kind of, almost COBOL-esque, syntax modification?

If you're wondering why I'm asking, it's for setting up stuff so that others with a not-as-geeky-as-I-am skillset can declare processing tasks.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for the power of Lisp macros. Beware...

Comment: Beware indeed! I fear that the staff I'm preparing this for would faint/freak/flail/flee at the sight of Lisp.

Comment: I wonder if anyone will mention the Logix language.

Comment: Or Lhogho for that matter.

Comment: Seeing what you want to do, I suggest you look at BDD frameworks.

Comment: If you're looking for something like Tcl or Clipper, why not just use Tcl or Clipper? Tcl is designed to be embedded in applications and used just like it seems you want to do.

Comment: You don't see it much outside mainframes, but [PLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I) has a macro language that lets you define your own statements, and the look much more COBOLesque than LISP ever will.

Comment: @boost: Why flee if Lisp has the features you are looking for?

Comment: @Giorgio: I can do Lisp. I rather like it in fact. But not all my colleagues and users feel the same. The Clipperesque/Tclish format appeals to the ones who'll be using it long after I've moved on.

Comment: @boost: I understand: Lisp has a reputation (with which I disagree) of being difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many languages out there that are quite flexible. Many (often newer) languages pride themselves in their suitability for domain-specific languages (DSLs). However, some of your examples need some macro system.

Some languages that prominently use macros:

- Lisp and descendants. These work as abstract syntax tree (AST) substitutions.
- C, C++. The C preprocessor uses token-level subtitution, and is less powerful than Lisp macros. Your first example can be directly translated to C macros:

  ```
  // untested
  #define repeat for(;;) {
  #define until(cond) if(cond) break; }

  auto n = 1;
  repeat {
    n++;
  } until(n > 100)
  ```

Many languages allow functions to be called with keywords. Examples include

- Lisps like Common Lisp.
- Smalltalk and descendants.
- Python:
- Some languages have syntax that allow to fake named arguments, e.g.

  - many command-line interfaces:

    ```
    git commit --file=foo.txt --message="Some fixes" --author=me
    ```
  - Any language with dictionary literals

    - Perl.
    - Javascript: `foo.bar({ x: 42, y: somethingElse })`.

Languages that have function literals/lambdas/closures don't *need* macros to define new control flow.

- Any functional language, e.g. Lisps, ML
- Smalltalk and descendants. Especially noteworthy is Ruby with its ubiquitous `do ... end` blocks.
- With clumsy syntax: C++11, Perl, Javascript.

There are some languages that have a flexible view on operators, so that a lot of punctuation like parens for function calls etc. can be left out. An example would be Scala.

Answer (score 4):

**Lisp macros** are probably a good examples of the kind of feature you are looking for. They basically allow you to extend the language in relatively arbitrary ways.

Effectively, a macro is a function that gets executed at compile time, and can produce whatever code you like. Lisps are well suited to this kind of technique because they are [homoiconic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) - which means that code is itself expressed in Lisp data structures. So your macro just needs to produce a data structure that represents the code that you want.

Here's an example from **Clojure** that adds a C-style `for` loop to the language:

```
(defmacro for-loop 
  "Runs an imperative for loop, binding sym to init, running code as long as check is true, 
  updating sym according to change"
  ([[sym init check change :as params] & code]
    `(loop [~sym ~init value# nil]
       (if ~check
         (recur ~change (do ~@code))
         value#))))

(for-loop [i, 0, (< i 10), (inc i)]
  (println i))
=> prints the numbers from 0 to 9 inclusive as you would expect
```

As you can see - it only takes a few lines of code to add a new language construct.

One caveat: this is a powerful technique and should be used with care. In general, you shouldn't use a macro when a normal function would do the job.